# What is the best way to persist filters, paging, sorting in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a .NET Core MVC application. For my CRUD operations, I have a basic Index.cshtml, Edit.cshtml and Create.cshtml page. In my Index.cshtml, I am able to sort, filter, page. I add this information to the query string, e.g.

```
https://localhost:5001/admin/myPage?search=my+search+string&page=3
```

Now, when I edit a row, I jump to another page. In the edit page, it might be possible, I would need to jump further to other pages. At the end, when I come back to my Index.cshtml page, I want to have my original filter applied.

I know I can pass the query string keys and values back and forth from page to page, but this looks rather complex to me.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Depends on your app... Cookies/LocalStorage? Session?

Comment: You can also go as far as storing data in a database for the user - in this way, a sort can be remembered the next time they log on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a session or cookie to store the filters, paging and sorting values. In the Index action method, you could check whether the parameter value is null, then, you could query the session and try to find the previous stored values and use them to filter or sort data. If the parameters are not null, you could update the session value.

Code like this (check the code related to the sortorder):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder,string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
    {
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        if(sortOrder != null)
        {
            //if sortOrder is not null, update the session to store the new sort order
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("sortOrder", sortOrder);
        }
        else
        {   //check if session contains the sort order.
            if(HttpContext.Session.GetString("sortOrder") != null)
            {
                //get sortOrder from session
                sortOrder = HttpContext.Session.GetString("sortOrder");
            }
            else
            {
                //session expired or is null, use the default sort order.
            }
        }

        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder; 
        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";


        var projects = from s in _context.Projects
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            projects = projects.Where(s => s.ProName.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                projects = projects.OrderBy(s => s.ProName);
                break; 
            default:
                projects = projects.OrderBy(s => s.ProID);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 3;
        return View(await PaginatedList<Projects>.CreateAsync(projects.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        
    }
```

You could refer to the following code to configure session in asp.net core (By default, the session timeout is 20 minutes, you could change it):

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); //set session expire time
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

More details information about using session management, please check [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will check to implement it like this.